# TFS access issue when check in files

Tags: tfs

I have a problem in TFS.

Actually, last time when we are working on ROM (my project name). We (john & me ) both had created a controller with same
name **ROController.cs** and we noticed this problem (same files Confilct), when we are checking files to TFS.

So, i deleted my file , and let john to check in his file.

Now ,the problem is that when i try to get lastest or even
access that ROController and its View. i got errors like

> "you do not have permissoin to access this file."

also in the team explorer , my file is shown as deleted, user name (me)

These are the files properly defining the error status.

[image]

This is the Error Shown

[image]

Comment: Did you made an undo of your changes and a Get Latest on that file from TFS?

Comment: yes. but the deleted file shows with a red cross

Comment: If you made an undo of your changes and a Get Latest after that, than your picture seems to be wrong, because it shows the file to be checked out and deleted by you. It also shows that you do not have the latest version in your workspace, because it says "Not downloaded". Revert your changes and get the one from your colleague should solve it.

Comment: i have get latest it to a new location too, but still same problem.

Comment: How did you delete the file? In TeamExplorer or in WindowsExplorer? Does it still show you the "delete" status for the file in TeamExplorer as in the picture? Have you made an "Undo pending changes" on that file?